# Convert from unsigned long hex to DWORD

Tags: c++, c

I need to convert from an `unsigned long` (hex) to a `DWORD`.

I normally would have

```
DWORD MyHex = 0x3F0000;
```

but instead I'm given

```
unsigned long MyLong = 3f0000;
```

How can I convert `MyLong` into `MyHex`?

It was fine when I was just visually printing it to a file and doing.

```
fprintf(pFile, "0x%X\n", MyLong);
```

But now I need to actually use that string as `DWORD`.

Comment: So the question is how to convert a string representation of a hex number to a `DWORD`? `unsigned long MyLong = 3f0000` won't compile so it's not at all clear.

Comment: I guess we could go with converting a string rep to a dword cause I could use sprintf to convert to char[256] and have it that way I guess...

Comment: Well make your mind up what it is you want.

Comment: You're `unsigned long MyLong = 3f0000;` should have `0x3f0000` I would assume (since `3f0000` isn't a valid numeric constant in C)? In that case, `MyHex` and `MyLong` are already identical values. It's notquite clear what you mean when you say "convert".

Comment: Whichever way you could make it work lol. 

Currently the program asks for me to manually type the address everytime I compile

DWORD MyOffset = 0x81231972 (I have to type this in everytime it changes)

I automatically get the new offset using another program and I print it out to a file using 

fprintf(pFile, "0x%X\n", MyLong);

So in the file it's like this 

0x2B71CC4

Then I take that and manually type it inthe other program, thats why I'm trying to avoid doing, the manual part of it.

Comment: So you want to know how to read the string "3f0000" from a file and calculate the DWORD value from that?

Comment: Yes Justin would certain be fine doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `DWORD` is actually just a typedef of `unsigned long`. There is no conversion necessary. You can use `MyLong` as if it were a `DWORD`.